# Merging with git checkout

Tags: git, github

Please consider a git repo with a single file `file.txt`. that contains a single word: "something" (no quotes). Then, `git add` and `git commit` (hash, let's say, 111a) the new file. Here is my `master`. Tag: v1.0.

Modify `file.txt` by adding new line "else" (no quotes). `git add` and `git commit` (hash 111b). Tag: v1.1.

Modify `file.txt` by adding new line "I do not" (no quotes). `git add` and `git commit` (hash 111c). Tag v1.2.

Create a branch `git branch v1.1/v1.12 111b`. `git checkout v1.2/v1.21`. Modify `file.txt` by adding new line "aaaa" (no quotes). `git add` and `git commit` (hash 111cc).

Now, according to [this manual](https://www.amazon.it/Version-Control-Git-collaborative-development/dp/1449316387/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1530110388&sr=8-3&keywords=git) (pp. 99-101) and the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout/1.5.5), `git checkout -m master` should make of master the current working directory plus merging the modification I made in the branch. It switches correctly, but no merge happens.

Likely, I am missing something obvious. I am aware the example is not a full reproduction of my working environment, but I hope it may be enough to explain the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-m` switch is considered only if there are uncommitted changes in the working directory.

And if there are changes in working directory, the result is not an automatic merge of content, but rather a merge conflict.